# Why is the output of this bash script different every time it is run?

Tags: shell, echo, sh

I have the following short bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /dev/null out.sh
while IFS=' ' read -r b c d e
do
    echo -ne "sendevent " >> out.sh
    echo -ne "/dev/input/event1 " >> out.sh
    echo -ne "$(( 0x$c )) " >> out.sh
    echo -ne "$(( 0x$d )) " >> out.sh
    echo -ne "$(( 0x$e )) " >> out.sh
    echo >> out.sh
done < "in.sh"
```

It takes in commands read from another script called `in.sh` in the form of `/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 0000006d`, and I need it to output to another script called `out.sh` in the form of `sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 109`, where it converts the latter three terms from hexadecimal to decimal.

However, when I run the script, I get a quasi-broken output, which changes each time I run it. The correct output should be along the lines of:

```
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 109
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 53 40
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 54 620
#and so on
```

Here's a picture of my actual output:

[image: out.sh screenshot]

Every time I run the script, the output is slightly different, and never uniform as I want it. Why does it output differently every time? How do I fix it so it outputs in the form I want it to?

I've tried adding in `sleep .01` after the last `echo` statement, and it did not fix the problem.

**EDIT:** As requested, here is a snippet of my `in.sh`:

```
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 0000006d
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0035 00000028
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0036 0000026c
/dev/input/event1: 0001 014a 00000001
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 ffffffff
/dev/input/event1: 0001 014a 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 0000006e
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0035 0000020f
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0036 000003dd
/dev/input/event1: 0001 014a 00000001
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 ffffffff
/dev/input/event1: 0001 014a 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 0000006f
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0035 000001b6
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0036 00000076
/dev/input/event1: 0001 014a 00000001
/dev/input/event1: 0000 0000 00000000
/dev/input/event1: 0003 0039 ffffffff
```

And here are two different outputs, run one after another, with the same `in.sh`:

```
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 109
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 54 620
sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 330 1
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 4294967295
/dev/input/event1 1 330 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 110
3 53 527
sendevent /dev/inp3 54 989
/dev/input/event1 1 330 1
sendevent 3 57 4294967295
sendevent /dev/input/event1 /event1 1 330 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 57 111
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 53 438 sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 54
sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 1
sendevent
sendevent /dev/input/event1 57 4294967295
/dev/input/event1 1 330 /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 112
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 53
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 54 881
sendevent /dev/input/event1
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 t1 0 0 0 4294967295
sendevent 1 330 0
sendevent/dev/input/event1 0 0 0
113
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 53
sendevent /dev/input/event1 54 901
/dev/input/event1 1 330 1
/dev/input/event1 0 0 0 sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 4294967295
330 0
```

And the second output:

```
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 109
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 53 620
sendevent /dev/input/event1  54 1 330 1 /dev/input/event1 0 0 0 sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 
sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 330
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 110
/dev/input/event1 3 53
sendevent /dev/input/event1 54 989
/dev/input/event1 1 330
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0
sendevent 3 57 4294967295
 sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 0
sendevent 0 0 0
put/event1 sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 111
sendevent 3 53 438
/event1 sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 54
sendevent /dev/input/event1 330 1
0 0 0
nt /dev/input/event1 sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 4294967295
sendevent 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 57 112
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 53 247
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 54 881 sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 330 1
/dev/input/event1 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event1 57 4294967295
sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 330
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0
sendevent 3 57 113
sendevent 3 53 246
/event1 sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 54
sendevent /dev/input/event1 330 1
/dev/input/event1 0 0 0
/dev/input/event1 3 57 4294967295 sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 330
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0
sendevent 3 57 114
/event1 sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 53
sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 54 882 sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 1
sendevent /dev/input/event1 0 0 0 sendevent /dev/input/event1 3 sendevent /dev/input/event1 1 0
sendevent 0 0 0
```

Comment: FYI, the POSIX-specified alternative to `echo -ne` is `printf '%b'`.

Comment: Are you trying to read the *script* `in.sh` or the output from `in.sh`? Because your script is currently reading the script files contents.

Comment: ...that said, you should **never** do code generation via string concatenation without using the shell's own escaping capabilities (ie. `printf '%q'`); down that path lies shell injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Can you provide a `in.sh` input file, and two different `out.sh` results?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was using `echo` over `printf` because I am going to be running the script on a more primitive device that only has `echo`

Comment: @ThePickleTickler, a device that doesn't have `printf` isn't likely to have `echo -e` either, and is by no means guaranteed to have `echo -n`. Unlike those features, `printf` is mandatory for POSIX compliance, so its availability is very widespread.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Duly noted, I may have to reconsider how to output after I finish the actual functionality of the script

Comment: @ThePickleTickler, ...for that matter, `printf` is built into bash *for every version ever published*, so the `bash` tag is inappropriate for any question which is going to be run on a shell which lacks it.

Comment: (...that said, the `printf %q` operation used in my code is a ksh and bash extension, so if you really do need to support a non-bash shell, that will need to be revised).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy removed the `bash` tag, added more examples with pictures

Comment: Pictures are actually problematic, since they can't be copied and pasted by someone trying to reproduce an issue. Much better to provide text (and even better than that if you've tested that combining your exact code and your exact text yield your exact output).

Comment: Hmm. On a filesystem that follows real POSIX semantics, these appends would be synchronous; I'm wondering if that's not the case here. What's the actual platform?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm working in Ubuntu 16.04, if that is what you are asking for?

Comment: Hmm. If you're getting this problem on Ubuntu, and using any normal/stock filesystem, that rules out issues at the kernel layer. Any chance more than one copy of the script could be running at the same time? Did you test that the **exact** code given in your question still produces the problem (assuming it's a simplified example from what you're actually doing)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I ran the exact code that is shown in the original question, and I am absolutely sure that only one copy of the script was running. The differing outputs are just snippets because they are files that are very long, but they follow the same form throughout

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I _really_ appreciate all your help, but you've already solved my main issue, so please don't feel like you have to keep helping me if you don't want to

Comment: Hmm. I can't reproduce the problem -- with your original code and the input you posted, I get precisely identical output from each run. Would probably need to investigate the execution environment to figure out exactly what's going on.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am using Ubuntu in a VM, could that affect it?

Comment: ...anyhow, if you don't feel it's worth your time to try to build a MCVE so folks who aren't you can reproduce the problem, there's absolutely no compulsion to do so. If you *did*, though, I'd be curious to see what the missing piece of the puzzle to reproduce it actually was.

Comment: ...no, running in a VM shouldn't be problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below uses an initial `grep` pass to sanitize input, avoiding potential shell injection attacks:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep '^[^ ]\+ [0-9a-f ]\+$' <in.sh | while IFS=' ' read -r _ c d e; do
  printf 'sendevent /dev/input/event1 %d %d %d\n' \
    "$(( 0x$c ))" "$(( 0x$d ))" "$(( 0x$e ))" 
done >out.sh
```

---

Note:

- `out.sh` is only opened a single time, rather than reopened before every command that wants to write to it, and closed after the end of that individual command (as happens with a `>>` operator on each write).
- Using `printf` once per line ensures that each write happens as an atomic syscall (when short enough lines are in use, as will reliably be the case here), and also avoids depending on behavior which [the POSIX specification for `echo` explicitly declines to specify](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html); the output of `echo -n` is explicitly undefined by the standard, whereas treating `-e` as an option rather than argument is actually contrary to the letter of the standard (and bash's default behavior doing so can be turned off, as with the combination of `set -o posix` and `shopt -s xpg_echo`).

Comment: Wow, I was trying to give you a `in.sh` and `out.sh` example, but your answer has already fixed my problem. Would you still like me to provide other code examples, for future reference? Thanks for the _really_ fast answer

Comment: If you can get things to the point of having a proper standalone reproducer that other folks can run to see the problem themselves, that would do a lot of good in terms of helping the question be useful to other people -- so if you don't mind going ahead with that effort, please do!